# How to find image outside of a package using a relative path

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So I'm trying to access an image i have stored in a res package further up in the structure of my application.

The structure looks like this

```
src
-> package1
-> -> innerPackage1
-> -> -> Test.java
-> res  
-> -> image.png
```

So I am trying to access the image from the inner class.
This is what I have tried so far plus many more variations of the path which never seemed to work.

```
URL resource = Test.class.getResource("/res/image.png");
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(resource));

ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("./res/image.png");
```

What has really confused me is I even tried putting the image directly into the same package as the java class and calling

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("image.png");
```

And even that didn't work, so now I am a complete standstill.

The only time it ever worked for me is when I moved the class file and the image file directly into the src file like so

```
src
-> Test.java
-> image.png
```

And then this finally worked:

```
new ImageIcon( "./src/image.png" )
```

I am now wondering if there is something wrong with my build path with the IDE I am using - intellij.

This application will be used on different devices so a relative path needs to be used.

Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried putting it in the resources folder and using an absolute path?

Comment: @jrtapsell I cannot use absolute path as this application is designed to work on different systems

Comment: Absolute relative to the Jar, rather than relative to the filesystem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folders structure in this project looks very unconventional. That should be:

```
src
|-main
   |-java
   |  |-package1
   |     |-innerPackage1
   |        |-Test.java   // although *Test* should be under src/test
   |-resources
      |-image.png
```

In IntelliJ project configuration, `src/main/java` should be marked as "sources root" and `src/main/resources` as "resources root". This can be done either in project settings or with rightclick on the folders.

After restructuring the project, the image should become accessible through `getResource("/image.png")`. Or, moved in `src/main/resources/package1/innerPackage1`, through `getResource("image.png")`.

#### Update

After a few tests with relative paths, using the original folders structure. 
`Test.class.getResource(".")` should return:

```
file:/{path to project}/{project name}/out/production/{project name}/package1/innerPackage1
```

So, if we call `Test.class.getResource("../..")`, we climb up to the root URL for pakaged contents:

```
file:/{path to project}/{project name}/out/production/{project name}/
```

Now if we call `Test.class.getResource("../../res/image.png")`, it should become accessible.

```
URL resource = Test.class.getResource("../../res/image.jpg");
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(resource));
```

*This should solve the issue, but it's far from a clean solution.*

`src` folder is considered by IntelliJ as "sources root" folder and it cannot contain a resources folder inside. `src` is not included into target paths, neither should `res`.

So I suggest moving the `res` folder at the same level as `src` and marking it as "resources root". After it the following should work properly:

```
URL resource = Test.class.getResource("/image.jpg");
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(resource));
```

Comment: I tried this but still getting the same error - the system cannot find the path specified

Comment: Should I be calling get resource on the 'Test' class, ie Test.class.getResource

Comment: How did you create the project in IntelliJ? What type of project is it? In project settings, what values do you have in "Modules -> Paths"? Have you tried to call `Test.class.getClassLoader().getResource(arg);`?

Comment: I cloned the project from a github repo. It is just a normal application as far as I know. There are no values? All it has checked is 'inherit project compile output path'. I just tried reinstalling intellij and using default settings for everything but still didn't work

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the issues and made a few tests. Some new suggestions are in the update of my answer above.

Comment: I have finally got it to work by reinstalling the jdk and using the default settings, it must have been an issue with my intellij settings as now if I hover over the resource path it loads the image showing that intellij has registered it. I'll accept your answer though as I appreciate the feedback on project structure and will use it in the future, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the context classloader via the current thread to get the image resource.

Something along these lines:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    URL resource = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("res/image.png");
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(resource));
}
```